# Close and restart a process after a certain time period in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that opens a certain exe and then, after (for example) 5 minutes, closes it then reopens it again. I have tried this:

```
@echo off
:loop
cd /d %~dp0
certain exe
timeout /t "time"  (by minutes)
taskkill /f /im "certain exe"
goto loop
```

but it wouldn't close the exe nor open it, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cmd will wait for the current command to end before executing the next command, so timeout (and taskill) will not be executed until example.exe closes by itself.

To ensure that cmd doesn't wait example.exe, you'll need to use `start /B`, as in this example:

```
@echo off
:loop
start /B "example.exe"
ping -n seconds_of_delay+1 127.0.0.1>nul
taskkill /f /im "example.exe"
goto :loop
```

Replace *seconds_of_delay+1* with the number of seconds you want the time period to last plus one.

/B is needed because, without it, start would execute example.exe in a new window (if you want that, simply use `start`).

I used ping as the way to create a time delay because it has been found to consume less processor time than sleep or timeout (you can find more details [here](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)).

Comment: I'd use `start "" /D "%~dp0." /B "example.exe"`. And what's wrong with `timeout`? (if you do want to use `ping`, you'll have to specify `ping -n seconds_of_delay` **`+1`** `localhost`!)

Comment: @aschipfl `ping` consumes less processor time than `sleep` or `timeout`, also `timeout` is less accurate on small periods of time (few seconds). It's explained more in detail on the link in my answer. And why would that `+1` be needed?

Comment: The `+1` is needed as `ping -n` does `n` attempts with `n-1` intervals, each of which lasting a second – this is also mentioned in the link you provided. Yes, `timeout` is less accurate, but only for its first run…

Comment: @aschipfl You are right, I didn't think of that. I'll edit my answer. I know that in this specific context timeout is virtually equivalent to the ping metod, but using ping for time delay is usually considered best practice (because of performance and accuracy), and I was trying to not reinforce bad habits.

Comment: Well, it always depends on context and on taste; in the current situation in a loop, `timeout` might even be better, because it actually does not wait the given time, but for the next second-tick, so it may even compensate the durations of the other commands in the loop; `ping` however just waits for the given time; on the other hand, `timeout` does not allow input redirection (`<`), which I consider a terrible design flaw…